# Show $(m^2+n^2)(o^2+p^2)(r^2+s^2) \geq 8mnoprs$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Let $m,n,o,p,r,s$ be positive numbers. Show that:

$$(m^2+n^2)(o^2+p^2)(r^2+s^2) \geq 8mnoprs$$

I tested an example,

let $m,n,o,p,r,s=1,2,3,4,5,6$ respectively. Then:

$$(1+4)(9+16)(25+30)=(5)(25)(55) \geq 8123456$$

but I get $6875$ which is not greater than the right side.

So am i misunderstanding the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: $m^2+n^2\geq 2mn$.

Comment: $8mnoprs=8123456$?

Comment: In your example $8mnoprs$ does not equal $8123456$; it means $8 \times 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 = 5760$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it's true for all real $m,n,o,p,r,s$. We know $x^2+y^2\ge 2|x||y|$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, because $(|x|-|y|)^2\ge 0$ for all $\forall x,y\in\Bbb R$.

$$(m^2+n^2)(o^2+p^2)(r^2+s^2) \geq (2|m||n|)(2|o||p|)(2|r||s|)\ge (2mn)(2op)(2rs)$$

Comment: A minor nitpick: the LHS being non-negative is not enough to be able to multiply the inequalities. (E.g. $1\geq -1$ and $1\geq -2$ but $1\not\geq 2$) It might be better to argue explicitly that $x^2+y^2\geq 2|xy|$.

Comment: @Dylan You're right, I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you misunderstood the problem, for $8mnoprs$ has tacit multiplication signs, it does not mean concatenation. Therefore, your test case is $$(1 + 4)(9 + 16)(25 + 30) = 6875 \geq 8 \times 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6.$$ But the first case I would test is the minimal case $m = n = o = p = r = s = 1$. Then $$2 \times 2 \times 2 \geq 8 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1.$$